# What part of this jQuery .replace is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I've read at least, ten different similar topics but haven't been able to figure out, what the problem is.

I am trying to change, part the url's in my header menu. Those url's, which contains "onepage" should be replaced with a hashtag.

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a class="level2" href="//test.com/products/iphone/iphone-onepage-32gb"><span>iPhone 32GB</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a class="level2" href="//test.com/products/iphone/iphone-onepage-64gb"><span>iPhone 64GB</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>



$('$('a[href*="onepage"]')').each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).text(text.replace(new RegExp("onepage","g"), "#");
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2EvGF/1517/)

```js
$('$('a[href *= "onepage"] ')').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text();
      $(this).text(text.replace(new RegExp("onepage", "g"), "#");
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a class="level2" href="//test.com/products/iphone/iphone-onepage-32gb"><span>iPhone 32GB</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a class="level2" href="//test.com/products/iphone/iphone-onepage-64gb"><span>iPhone 64GB</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: for demo you can use `<>` in SO

Comment: you have extra `$`. It should be `$('a[href *= "onepage"]')`

Comment: `$('$('a[href *= "onepage"] ')')` <- This part.

Comment: and use .attr('href') instead not .text()

Comment: @Tushar And the rest. The whole code is FUBAR...

Comment: .each() seems useless for this case too.

Comment: @Pirs I disagree... using `each` is only part of code shown that makes sense

Comment: What are expected results?

Comment: @charlietfl he should work directy with the attr() like `.attr( "href", function( arg ) {
  /* code */
});`

Comment: @Pirs that is certainly one way but so is using `each` as you did yourself in your own answer

Comment: @charlietfl because i let it in his mind way, but he should do ;)

Comment: @Pirs but the comment was simply ...  *"each() seems useless here"* ... but your own answer disproves that and therefore the comment is misleading and can certinaly confuse the OP

Comment: @charlietfl for sure, i did to stay in his logic, but, he could use another way to do that directly with attr(), and i dont risk to lose point because its too original or what.. a comment is enough, experience says.

Comment: @Pirs the point is then ... make comments meaningful or don't post them

Comment: @charlietfl i agree yes, isnt the best way for him to read the entire jquery doc to learn instead admit the answer, dont you see he needs to do that ?

Comment: @charlietfl you win i did it...

Answer (score 0):

You should change the href instead of the text. Also, you have your css selector wrong.

```js
$('a[href*="onepage"]').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).prop("href");
    // change the property href to new url
    $(this).prop("href", href.replace(new RegExp("onepage", "g"), "#"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a class="level2" href="//test.com/products/iphone/iphone-onepage-32gb"><span>iPhone 32GB</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a class="level2" href="//test.com/products/iphone/iphone-onepage-64gb"><span>iPhone 64GB</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href*="onepage"]').each(function() {
        var str = $(this).attr('href').replace(/onepage/, "#");
        $(this).attr('href',str);
});
```

or

```
$('a[href*="onepage"]').attr( "href", function( i, val ) {
  return val.replace(/onepage/, "#");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use plain javascript to change the `href` property, see following please:

```js
$('a[href*="onepage"]').each(function() {
  this.href = this.href.replace(/onepage/, "#");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a class="level2" href="//test.com/products/iphone/iphone-onepage-32gb"><span>iPhone 32GB</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a class="level2" href="//test.com/products/iphone/iphone-onepage-64gb"><span>iPhone 64GB</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```